# How to point Dns and manage Nginx redirection properly

Tags: nginx, dns, ip

I am facing the following situation: 
I own a domain name, let's say example.com at name.com
We have a website hosted at bluehost on a shared hosting with an IP1
We have an ERP (odoo) hosted at digitalocean on a droplet where Nginx is running and where IP2 is allocated.
The erp is accesible via IP2:port_number
I am trying to redirect erp.example.com in direction of odoo while keeping the main domaine http://example.com to point to IP1

I have tried to setup two A record. One for erp.example.com to point to IP2 but here I can not specify the port at name.com, problem is it doesn't seems even to point on the 80 port as I don't see the Nginx welcome page when I type http://erp.example.com

I have setup another A record which point to the bluehost IP1 on a wordpress website and this works fine.

DNS are recorded with two ns of bluehost only.

Based on my understanding I should point the erp.example.com to IP2, then set nginx to filter erp.example.com to go to IP2:port with a redirection ?

I don't understand why my A record pointing to IP2 doesn't direct me to the digital ocean server. In Chrome it gives me a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED .

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could work if you set dns A record to point just one server(one with www) and set the nginx:
 - one block to point to Odoo (reverse proxy to IP1 address)
 - other to redirect to IP2(your www)

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name http://erp.example.com;

     location / {

proxy_pass http://ipOfYouOdoo:8069;

proxy_redirect off;

proxy_set_header Host $host;

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_read_timeout 3000000;

client_max_body_size 2000M;

}
}

server {

listen 80;

server_name http://www.axample.com;

 location / {

 root /var/www/static;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You've to point `example.com` to *IP1* and `erp.example.com` to *IP2* through your DNS manager (name.com in your case).
You can't define port in DNS level. You've to configure in nginx with a redirection, since the default http port is 80. You could try `proxy_pass` alternatively if you don't want to do redirection.
After setting up your A records, try pinging to both domains to make sure it is working. Sometimes it may take some time to reflect the changes due to DNS cache.

Comment: strangely when I type erp.example.com I don't get the homepage of nginx... this is what I don't understand...yet I have pointed erp.example.com to the IP of the server where Nginx is setup?

Comment: @user92481 If you ping `erp.example.com` and see the correct IP, it depends how nginx is configured at this point. You can try Piotr Cierkosz's nginx configuration.